# Xna draw order not working right

Tags: c#, xna

I have an 2d array of Texture2D, it holds the different parts of the map in this array. I have a problem though, when I run the game, the map is drawn correctly but for some reason the array[0, 0] texture overlaps all my textures including my player texture and mouse texture. Every other texture works as my mouse and player texture correctly overlaps the map.

I'm really confused right now as the map textures are being drawn together using a nested for loop.

Here is my draw method for my map which I call in the Game's Draw method:

```
public void Draw()
{
    // Draws the Map from a 2D Array
    for (int row = 0; row < mapTexture.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < mapTexture.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(mapTexture[row, col], mapPosition[row, col], Color.White);
        }//end for
    }//end for
}//end Draw()
```

My actual draw method:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
    spriteBatch.Draw(mouseIcon, mouseIconPosition, Color.White);
    player.Draw();
    map.Draw();
    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}//end Draw()
```

Comment: where are you drawing your mouse and player?

Comment: edit it into your question

Comment: are you sure that your mouse is on top of the rest of the map?  judging from the code you've posted, it shouldn't be

Comment: Yup, its ontop of the player, and the player is on top of the map. Well, except the top right peice of the map of course.

Comment: I have also tried doing FrontToBack but I see no difference.

Comment: And if I invert the order that those are drawn, it ends up the whole map covers my player and mouse.

Comment: Try inverting the order that they're drawn, **AND** use `SpriteSortMode.Deferred`

Comment: ANd how are you populatin your `mapTexture` array?

Comment: That Worked! Nice. If you don't mind me asking, what does changing the SortMode to Deferred mean?

Comment: The documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx  It looks like it doesn't take into account `layerDepth`

Comment: and I was actually confused by your problem, because it doesn't look like you're passing `layerDepth` to your `spriteBatch.Draw` calls, but Your problem sounded like a `layerDepth` - related problem.

Comment: Ya, I'm pretty new to xna. So, I'm not even sure how to use layerDepth. I'm guessing its just a way to keep objects from overlapping. I'll have to look on google how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inverting the order that they're drawn, AND use `SpriteSortMode.Deferred`

Answer (score 0):

You can try use overloaded SpriteBatch.Draw method with **depth**. As example:

> **SpriteBatch.Draw (Texture2D, Vector2, Nullable, Color, Single, Vector2, Single, SpriteEffects, Single)** Adds a sprite to the batch of sprites to be rendered, specifying the texture, screen position, optional source rectangle, color tint, rotation, origin, scale, effects, and sort depth.

or can try change order for drawing:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend);

    map.Draw();  // first
    player.Draw();  // second
    spriteBatch.Draw(mouseIcon, mouseIconPosition, Color.White); // third

    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}//end Draw()
```

(its for SpriteSortMode.Deferred)

P.S. Sorry for google-translating

oops... I have not updated comments before responding