# Debugging SpriteBatch.Draw

Tags: c#, xna

Problem: When an if clause is put around a spriteBatch.Draw statement, it seems to affect other spriteBatch.Draw that is outside the if clause .

This is (part of) the code in the Draw method:

```
if(OvertakeMouseHover == true)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(OvertakeButton, OvertakeButtonPosition, Color.White);
}
spriteBatch.Draw(Car1, Car1Position, Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(Car2, Car2Position, Color.White);
```

And this is the code setting `OvertakeMouseHover`:

```
if (mouse.X > OvertakeButtonPosition.X && mouse.X < OvertakeButtonPosition.X + OvertakeButton.Width &&
   mouse.Y > OvertakeButtonPosition.Y && mouse.Y < OvertakeButtonPosition.Y + OvertakeButton.Height)
{
   //Overtake button mouseover
   OvertakeMouseHover = true;
}
else
{
   OvertakeMouseHover = false;
}
```

When running the above code, `OvertakeButton` appears as expected (ie when the mouse is hovering over its location). `Car2` appears as expected (all the time). However `Car1`, rather than appearing all the time, appears and disappears with the `OvertakeButton`, as though `spriteBatch.Draw(Car1...)` is within the if statement.

The following code makes all 3 sprites appear all the time:

```
//if(OvertakeMouseHover == true)
//{
    spriteBatch.Draw(OvertakeButton, OvertakeButtonPosition, Color.White);
//}
spriteBatch.Draw(Car1, Car1Position, Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(Car2, Car2Position, Color.White);
```

I can't for the life of me work out why `spriteBatch.Draw(Car1..)` is affected by the if statement, but it definitely looks like it is to me. All ideas welcome!

EDIT - and this code makes all 3 sprite appear and disappear with the `MouseHover`. It's as though the bracket is one line lower than it should be:

```
if (OvertakeMouseHover == true)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(OvertakeButton, OvertakeButtonPosition, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(Car1, Car1Position, Color.White);
}
spriteBatch.Draw(Car2, Car2Position, Color.White);
```

EDIT 2. Okay this is to do with the image appearing in front/behind of my background. In which case the issue is to do with sorting. How do I force the sorting order? I assumed it was just back to front in order of the code but that doesn't seem to be it.

EDIT 3. Entire draw method. Currently investigating what the various sort options do.

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Backtofront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
spriteBatch.Draw(RaceBackground, BackgroundPosition, Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(Car1, Car1Position, Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(Car2, Car2Position, Color.White); 
if (OvertakeMouseHover == true)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(OvertakeButton, OvertakeButtonPosition, Color.White);
}        

string output = Car1Speed.ToString();

// Find the center of the string
Vector2 FontOrigin = Font1.MeasureString(output) / 2;
// Draw the string
spriteBatch.DrawString(Font1, output, FontPos, Color.LightGreen,
    0, FontOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.5f);
spriteBatch.End();
// TODO: Add your drawing code here

base.Draw(gameTime);
```

Comment: Can we see the entire draw method if it isn't too long?

Comment: Switching the sortmode to deferred seems to do the trick. Why though?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `SpriteBatch.Begin` with `SpriteSortMode.Deferred`

Deferred guarantees that your sprites will be drawn in the order that you called the `Draw` method for them.

> Deferred
>
> Sprites are not drawn until End is called. End will apply graphics
>   device settings and draw all the sprites in one batch, in the same
>   order calls to Draw were received. This mode allows Draw calls to two
>   or more instances of SpriteBatch without introducing conflicting
>   graphics device settings. SpriteBatch defaults to Deferred mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx

according to the documentation, `BackToFront` says that it works the same as deferred, except that it takes depth into account, but you might be running into a bug with it.  This is [not the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618343/xna-draw-order-not-working-right) that I would have seen this bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SpriteSortMode.BackToFront` you need to specify the depth of each sprite, otherwise the game will draw them at the same time, making them to "flicker".
You may need to use a different `SpriteBatch.Draw` overload that has `float layerDepth` parameter, something like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx):

```
public void Draw (
     Texture2D texture,
     Vector2 position,
     Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
     Color color,
     float rotation,
     Vector2 origin,
     float scale,
     SpriteEffects effects,
     float layerDepth
)
```

Or better, as *Sam I am* previously wrote, use `SpriteSortMode.Deferred` which is easier to use and understand.